# Continuitiy in multivariable function: I suspect I can simplify some more but can't see how

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to analyze continuity for the following function defined by parts at $(0,0)$:

$$f(x,y)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll} \frac{x^4 + \sin(y^4)}{x^2+y^2} & if \; (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0 &if \;(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{array}\right.$$

I tried a few approximations that I managed to solve to 0. But then I tried this approximation when $x \rightarrow 0 ; y=x^2$ and this is how far I got:

$$
\frac{x^4 +\sin(x^8)}{x^2+x^4} = \frac{x^4 + \sin(x^8)}{x^2(1+x^2)} \frac{x^6}{x^6} = \frac{x^4}{x^8(1+x^2)}+\frac{\sin(x^8)}{x^8}\frac{x^6}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{x^4(1+x^2)}+\frac{x^6}{1+x^2}
$$
I don't see what else I can do here, and I'm still getting a 0 in the denominator since $x \rightarrow 0$

So I tried compression, and also got stuck:

$$
|\frac{x^4 + \sin(y^4)}{x^2+y^2}|= \frac{x^4 + |\sin(y^4)|}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x^2\cdot x^2}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{|\sin(y^4)|}{x^2+y^2} \le x^2\cdot 1 + \frac{|\sin(y^4)|}{x^2+y^2}
$$

Any clues? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Why don't you try with the inequality $|\sin(t)|\leq |t|$? Therefore near the origin
$$|f(x,y)|=\left|\frac{x^4 + \sin(y^4)}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2+y^2}
\leq \frac{(x^2 + y^2)^2}{x^2+y^2}=x^2+y^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use

$|\sin(y^4)|\leq y^4$

and polar coordinates to get

$|f(x,y)|\leq 2r^2$ and conclude.